# How do I move to another line when I'm stuck inside angle brackets?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio

[image]

I use Visual Studio Express for the web.

I noticed that when I write an HTML markup such as h1, Visual Studio completes the tag for me. However, in this case I become inside the tag so when I finish writing my text I have to use the mouse to skip to the second line. If I press Enter rather than using the mouse then this will cause the ending tag for h1 element to be in the second line!

Is there a way using the keyboard to skip to the second line when I'm inside HTML tag?

Comment: Press `end` then `enter`?

Comment: Very helpful but the problem is the end key in my keyboard is not not close to the enter key, is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>End</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> will insert a blank line underneath the current line, and move the cursor to it. It will indent to the current level.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will insert a blank line below the current line, and move the cursor to it. It will not indent to the current level.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will insert a blank line above the current line, and move the cursor to it. It will not indent to the current level.

---

These can be customised via `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard` ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx))

Some items of interest are:

```
Edit.LineEnd
Edit.LineOpenBelow
Edit.LineOpenAbove
```